# Weird printing behaviour in java threads

Tags: java, java-threads

I am new to coding and wrote a very simple java code using the concept of threads. I tried printing two statements "good morning" and "welcome" infinitely using two different threads from two classes to see the behaviour of the threads. However during multiple runs I noticed that sometimes in the output the first line showed incomplete text although not in every single run. Can someone explain what's going on?

```
    class Mythread1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("good morning");
        }
    }
}
class Mythread2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("welcome");
        }
    }
}
public class threads{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mythread1 t1=new Mythread1();
        Mythread2 t2=new Mythread2();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

```
rning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
welcome
```

I paused the output since it was infinite.

Running again

```
ng
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
good morning
```

Comment: *I paused the output since it was infinite.* Smells like your terminal has a buffer limit and it's just discarding the oldest characters.

Comment: Maybe your output window (e.g. console) runs out of space? Or is this also happening with for example ten prints?

Comment: Spewing text as fast as possible is going to stress your terminal emulator. Perhaps consider some delays in your tight loops.

Comment: The terminal display has nothing to do with Java

Answer (score 0):

I guess you expected a thing such as:

```
good morning
good morning
welcome
good morning
welcome
good morning
welcome
welcome
...
```

But the thing happen here is thread is not stay forever and executed parallel with each other. It execute then jump, execute then jump, .... Beside, the while(true) is execute too fast that will confuse you at the first time, if you set thread.sleep(10) result will much observables

Try this:

```
class Mythread1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("good morning");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
    }
}
class Mythread2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("welcome");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class threads{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mythread1 t1=new Mythread1();
        Mythread2 t2=new Mythread2();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried with the sleep method and this time it was normal.

Comment: just realised it has nothing to do with threads themselves since i tried to print "good morning" in a normal infinte while loop and the same problem occured'

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same if you change your code to,

```
class Mythread1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("good morning");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Mythread2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("welcome");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A `while(true)` loop is something executed very fast.
Moreover, you could use `PrintWriter` instead of the slow `System.out.println`.

```
class Mythread1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        while (true) {
            writer.println("good morning");
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
}
class Mythread2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        while (true) {
            writer.println("welcome");
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its normal after i tried with the sleep method

Comment: i tried printing good morning in a regular while infinte loop and the same problem occured. It seems the problem lies with the infinte loop itself and not threads.